# XML files in java classpath not being found

Tags: java, xml, jar, manifest

I've been trying to get some config files added into a JAR manifests class-path. Things like Spring, Log4j files etc... when I run the jar, it picks up other jars on the classpath so it can run the application starter class (which is in another jar) but it only looks for the XML files in the directory the jar is located, even though I can see it's path on the manifest.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: What does classpath have to do with XML files? As far as I understand it, classpath is for class loading. To access files in a JAR, Object.getResource() is usually used. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Sergey: resources also go on the classpath (think log4j.properties)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I put it a wrong way. But stwb says that "it only looks for the XML files in the directory the jar is located" so it seems to me that he is trying to access them as normal files, not as resources, that was my main point.

Comment: When it gets to the part in the code where it looks for default.log4j.properties, it only looks in /project/dist, the location of the JAR file of our project. The actual path of the XML file, project/resources, is included in the classpath in the manifest but it doesn't check there, it just says "Cannot find project/dist/default.log4j.properties". However, it does pick up the path of the JAR which contains the main class, in project/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it with verbose class loading switch on java command line to make sure classes in jars are actually being loaded.

There is a line length limit of 72 bytes in MANIFEST.MF - make sure you don't have a long lines there.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Notes%20on%20Manifest%20and%20Signature%20Files

Comment: Thanks maximdim. The line is pretty long. Would the first 72 bytes get read or would the whole thing just be ignored? Also, is there a way to have two multiple classpath definitions without overwriting the previous ones?

Comment: No line may be longer than 72 bytes (not characters), in its
UTF8-encoded form. If a value would make the initial line longer than this, it should be continued on extra lines (each starting with a single SPACE). It's best to use build tools such as ant or maven to generate manifest file for you - they will handle this properly

Comment: Oh, ok, well I am using Ant so that must not be the problem. I've decided to try a different route and go with trying to run the jar from the Ant build file instead. Just do a <java> with a jar attribute and set the class path in it. Hopefully that'll yield better results.

Comment: Did you find an answer ? I have the same problem... I can't load log4j2.xml via the classpath of the manifest.mf file. How can I do it ?